# Remove certain characters if on end of string in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of names in which I have made all uppercase, removed spaces, and non-alphabetic characters to more easily merge with another list -- both are in pandas dataframe.

One of the dataframe's names have some names with `JR` attached to the end while their counterparts in the other dataframe to not contain this suffix. How can I strip all `JR` from both?

I tried something like the following:

`df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].str.replace('JR','')`

but I think this would remove all instances of `JR` and not when it is the last 2 characters. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about: `df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].apply(lambda x: x[:-2] if x.endswith('JR') else x)`

Answer (score 4):

You could use replace with a regex:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=['Name JR', 'Name JR Middle', 'JR Name'], columns=['name'])
df['name'] = df.name.str.replace(r'\bJR$', '', regex=True).str.strip()

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
             name
0            Name
1  Name JR Middle
2         JR Name
```

The pattern `'\bJR$'` matches the word JR only at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
def jr_replace(x):
    match = re.sub(r'JR$',"",x)
    return match

df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].apply(jr_replace)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to remove `JR` using `string.endswith`, and remove it from the rows that contain it sclicing the `str` object:

```
m = s.str.endswith('JR')
s.loc[m] = s.loc[m].str[:-2]
```

---

**Example**

Using @danielmesejo's dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['Name JR', 'Name JR Middle', 'JR Name'], columns=['name'])
m = df.name.str.endswith('JR')
df.name.loc[m] =  df.name.loc[m].str[:-2]

            name
0           Name 
1  Name JR Middle
2         JR Name
```